# Get ClassTag implicitly for abstract type

Tags: scala, classtag

I'm trying to get ClassTag implicitly. I have the following trait:

```
trait Tst{ self =>
  type T
  def getCls = getCls0[T] //no classtag
  private def getCls0[T](implicit ev: ClassTag[T]) = ev.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
}

class Tsss extends Tst {
  override type T = String
}
```

Is there a way to get `ClassTag` by the type variable declaration implicitly without specifying it explicitly?

The thing is I'm trying to make the code as easy to use for clients as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use abstract classes, implicit parameters and generics instead of parametric types:

```
abstract class Tst[T](implicit ev: ClassTag[T]) { self =>
  def getCls = getCls0[T] //no classtag
  private def getCls0[T](implicit ev: ClassTag[T]) = 
    ev.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
}

class Tsss extends Tst[String]
```

Note that although Dotty supports traits with parameters, it does not mix as well with generics.

Comment: It's a bit confusing to have shadowing `T` and `ev` (though of course `T` is in the original question). I'd just inline `getCls0`'s body and remove it.